# Continue build with lint warnings

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, lint, gradlew

I have a `build.gradle` file for an android project.It says

```
android {
lintOptions {      
   quiet false
   abortOnError true
   ignoreWarnings true
   }
   ...
}
```

My requirement is like it should get aborted only if there are errors. If warnings are present just continue with the build.How can we do that?

Also I tried running the lint from command line as

```
lint path-to-project
```

This gives an error `To correctly analyze Gradle projects, you should run "gradlew :lint" instead`. Please help me to resolve this also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding **checkReleaseBuilds** inside **lintoptions**

Like this

```
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}
```

Second issue can be resolved using following commands

```
cd PATH_TO_PROJECT
chmod a+x gradlew
./gradlew lint
```

This will work.

Comment: It worked..Do you have any idea on second part of the question

Comment: I have added one link to the answer it may help you